# Add a child XMLElement to Existing XML

Tags: xml, database, oracle, oracle11g

I am creating a parent XML using a loop and I want to insert another XML inside it. Is there a way I can insert my 2nd XML inside first XML ?

OUTER LOOP FOR EACH FAMILY

INNER LOOP FOR EACH FAMILY's GRANDKIDS

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT ("grandkids"    
                       ,XMLELEMENT("kid1", 'ron')  
                       ,XMLELEMENT("age", '12')  
) INTO TESTXML2 FROM DUAL;
```

END GRANDKIDS LOOP;

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT ("Family"  
                     ,XMLELEMENT("father", 'myFather')  
                     ,XMLELEMENT("mother", 'myMother')  
                     ,XMLELEMENT("children", '2')  
                             <---INSERT TESTXML2 HERE--->
) INTO TESTXML FROM DUAL;
```

END FAMILY LOOP;

How can I insert TESTXML2 inside TESTXML1 ?

It can be either be inserted while FamilyXML is created or Update after FamilyXML  has been inserted into database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either just refer to your `testxml2` variable:

```
declare
  testxml xmltype;
  testxml2 xmltype;
begin

SELECT XMLELEMENT ("grandkids"    
                       ,XMLELEMENT("kid1", 'ron')  
                       ,XMLELEMENT("age", '12')  
) INTO TESTXML2 FROM DUAL; 

dbms_output.put_line(testxml2.getstringval());

SELECT XMLELEMENT ("Family"  
                     ,XMLELEMENT("father", 'myFather')  
                     ,XMLELEMENT("mother", 'myMother')  
                     ,XMLELEMENT("children", '2')  
                     ,testxml2
) INTO TESTXML FROM DUAL; 

dbms_output.put_line(testxml.getstringval());

end;
/

<grandkids><kid1>ron</kid1><age>12</age></grandkids>
<Family><father>myFather</father><mother>myMother</mother><children>2</children><grandkids><kid1>ron</kid1><age>12</age></grandkids></Family>

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Or put all the nested XMLElement calls in one query:

```
declare
  testxml xmltype;
begin

SELECT XMLELEMENT ("Family"  
                     ,XMLELEMENT("father", 'myFather')  
                     ,XMLELEMENT("mother", 'myMother')  
                     ,XMLELEMENT("children", '2')  
                     ,XMLELEMENT ("grandkids"    
                       ,XMLELEMENT("kid1", 'ron')  
                       ,XMLELEMENT("age", '12')  
                      )
) INTO TESTXML FROM DUAL; 

dbms_output.put_line(testxml.getstringval());

end;
/

<Family><father>myFather</father><mother>myMother</mother><children>2</children><grandkids><kid1>ron</kid1><age>12</age></grandkids></Family>

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If you're actually getting data from tables then look at XMLAgg, XMLForest etc.